# Convert numpy array to pandas dataframe with labels from list

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, numpy

please advise how to perform the following permutations:

```
array = [1, 3, 2]  # numpy.ndarray

l1 = ['foo_qwe1_ert1', 'bar_qwe2_ert2', 'baz_qwe3_ert3']  # list
```

I need to get the following pandas dataframe:

| Column1 | Column2 | Column3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| foo | qwe1 | ert1 |
| baz | qwe3 | ert3 |
| bar | qwe2 | ert2 |

the problem is the list contains text labels from 0 to 30 (format: XXX_YYY_ZZZ) and numpy.array has shape (3536,) and contains numbers from 0 to 30. I need to assign label for each number in array and save it as pandas dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First use `DataFrame` constructor with `split`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([x.split('_') for x in l1], columns=['Column1', 'Column2', 'Column3'])
print (df)
  Column1 Column2 Column3
0     foo    qwe1    ert1
1     bar    qwe2    ert2
2     baz    qwe3    ert3
```

And then change order by `array` by extract last integer from last column:

```
df.index = df['Column3'].str.extract('(\d+)$', expand=False).astype(int)
df = df.loc[array].reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
  Column1 Column2 Column3
0     foo    qwe1    ert1
1     baz    qwe3    ert3
2     bar    qwe2    ert2
```

EDIT:

```
array = np.array([1, 3, 2])
l1 = ['foo_qwe1_ert1', 'bar_qwe2_ert2', 'baz_qwe3_ert3'] 

L = [x.split('_') for x in l1]
a, b, c = L[0]
b = b.replace('1','')
c = c.replace('1','')
print (b, c)
qwe ert

out = [(y[0], f'{b}{x}', f'{c}{x}') for x, y in zip(array, L)]
print (out)
[('foo', 'qwe1', 'ert1'), ('bar', 'qwe3', 'ert3'), ('baz', 'qwe2', 'ert2')]
```

Or:

```
out = [(y[0], f'qwe{x}', f'ert{x}') for x, y in zip(array, L)]
print (out)
[('foo', 'qwe1', 'ert1'), ('bar', 'qwe3', 'ert3'), ('baz', 'qwe2', 'ert2')]
```

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame(out, columns=['Column1', 'Column2', 'Column3'])
print (df)
  Column1 Column2 Column3
0     foo    qwe1    ert1
1     bar    qwe3    ert3
2     baz    qwe2    ert2
```

Comment: thanks, but the problem is the list contains text labels from 0 to 30(format: XXX_YYY_ZZZ) and numpy.array has shape (3536,) and contains numbers from 0 to 30. I need to assign label for each number in array and save it as pandas dataframe

Comment: @AndreyAndrey - Is possible change question by this new sample data?

Comment: @AndreyAndrey - not sure if understand, so need cretae input list by `array`? Like in EDIT?